# How to connect my android app to MySQL through PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, database, httpurlconnection

I would like to connect my android app to a MySQL table I have on Hostinger.
The layout is really simple: a simple TextView whose text has to be filled through a string with the setText.

I made sure I used the most up to date library (HttpURLConnection), that the PHP file on the server is well done, that I properly parse and that the app can connect to the internet through specification in the Manifest file.

Yet, when I open the app, I just see a black page and there is no error on the logcat. Any idea of what could it be?

This is my Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/result"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

while this is my MainActivity

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

```
String line=null;
String [] stream_name;
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
String value;

TextView resultView;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    StrictMode.enableDefaults(); //STRICT MODE ENABLED
    resultView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
}

public void getData(){
    String result = "";
    InputStream isr = null;
    try{
        URL url = new URL ("http://31.170.165.234/public_html/AH_Bread2.php");
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.connect();
        isr = urlConnection.getInputStream();

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        resultView.setText("Couldn't connect to database");
    }
    //convert response to string
    try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        isr.close();

        result=sb.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error  converting result "+e.toString());
    }

    //parse json data
    try {
        String s = "";
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

        for(int i=0; i<jArray.length();i++){
            JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            s = s +
                    "Price : "+json.getString("Price")+"\n"+
                    "Weight : "+json.getInt("Weight")+"\n"+
                    "Price/Weight : "+json.getString("P/W")+"\n\n";

        }

        resultView.setText(s);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error Parsing Data "+e.toString());
    }
}

}
```

And this is my PHP file on the server

```
<?php

$mysqli = NEW MySQL('marcodr.byethost7.com','xxxxxx','xxxxxx','xxxxxx');

$resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM TABLE 1 WHERE ID = 'xxxx'");

if($resultSet->num_rows != 0){

while($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())
{
$ID = $rows['ID'];
$Price = $rows['Price'];
$Weight = $rows['Weight'];
$PW = $rows['PW'];


print(json_encode($rows);
}
}else{
echo "No results.";
}
?>
```

As you can see, my database is really simple: only four columns, properly named "ID", "Price", "Weight" and "P/W".

I would simply want to set the text of the TextView (identified through the FindViewById) to the string "s" defined by the end of the Java class, but it's not working despite all the checks! Any idea?

Comment: Well the url returns a 404

Comment: @Steve **302** status returned to me

Comment: Thanks Steve; do you think the PHP is the problem?
this is my database (it's REALLY basic)
http://postimg.org/image/3pvw6zqpd/

Comment: @MDR Steve just points you that your link `http://31.170.165.234/public_html/AH_Bread2.php` seems to be not valid. It doesn't matter what you are trying to do inside your php script because you script never get executed so far.

Comment: Thanks @Alex, I've just amended the typo. Still, the errored page pops up
http://postimg.org/image/7s6zagv6h/ that's my overview of the server, I literally copied and pasted the calues, what could possibly be wrong?

Comment: we don't care about *my overview of the server,* your page should responds from internet. but so far it is not.  did you visit  your script through browser? `http://31.170.165.234/public_html/AH_Bread2.php`? do yuo see any `echo`s?

Comment: do you have any domain name linked to this hosting account?

Comment: **WARNING**: You've posted your database credentials on the public internet. I strongly recommend you change that password immediately. Next time, please be careful to avoid posting that sort of information for your own security.

Comment: tadman, thanks I have already changed it :)
@Alex, nope I didn't visit the script, and I only set one echo in the PHP, nothing else that I have touched. Last but not least, I do have one name linked to this account. What should I do?

Comment: try to visit the page using your domain name like: `http://yourdomain.com/AH_Bread2.php`

Comment: thanks a lot @Alex I got one step closer to the solution, but I'm not there yet. Is it possibly Hostinger being so hostile?
Anyway, the domain is down/not available, but I can see the preview. Is it normal?
Yet the preview says "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$resultSet' (T_VARIABLE) in /home/u136947080/public_html/AH_Bread.php on line 5"

Comment: I also tried this Spanish solution http://www.hostinger.es/forum/asistencia-al-cliente/382-error-404-hostinger-resuelto.html
but voiding the cache hasn't helped!

Comment: Well the php has a bunch of errors, but until the url is accessible (eg in your browser) theres no point getting to that

Comment: yes, as I open the link from Hostinger the page is "Not available". I'd have to open a ticket.
Any idea where I could find a good template of php? I fixed that one and it now says that there's a wrong { in line 7 -.-

Comment: Concentrate on getting the hosting to work, then you can move onto the php. Im sure there are tons of other errors anyway - for a start you are treating the response as JSON in your java, but its not JSON, its HTML (or, at least it would be, if the php worked!)

Comment: still 5 hours to open a new ticket

Which other websites would you recommend in place of Hostinger?

Comment: there are tons of cheap php hosts. I usually work with our companies servers, but i have used https://krystal.co.uk/hosting/ before and they where excellent for customer support, but they are UK based, i have no idea where you are in the world

Comment: Oh i just noticed hostinger is free - all free hosts suck, no exceptions

Comment: time is mon€y, 000webhost is already working. I uploaded "AH_Bread.php" and it says "unexpected '=' on line 14"

my code is 

<?php

$mysqli = NEW MySQLi 

('xxxxxxxx','xxxxxxx','xxxxx','xxxxxxxxx');

$resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM TABLE 1 WHERE ID = 'xxxx'");

if($resultSet->num_rows != 0){

while($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())
{
$ID = $rows['ID'];
$Price = $rows['Price'];
$Weight = $rows['Weight'];
$P/W = $rows['P/W'];


echo "<p>Price: $Price<br />P/W: $P/W</p>";

}else{
echo "No results.";
}
?>

how can an equal be considered as wrong?

Comment: Could you edit your question with your current code - its too hard to read it in a comment. Also, post the 000webhost url

Comment: Sure, Steve, thanks. Php updated and webhost is http://mdr.hostzi.com/

this php is turning me insane

Comment: http://pastebin.com/RYVYYjL8 Your specific issue was an illegal char in the variable name (`$P/W`) but there where other syntax errors as well

Comment: thanks @Steve! It seems like it only argues against the lack of database. Juggling between Hostinger and 000webhost is a pain in the neck, harmed the FTP and now I exceeded in login attempts, brb but thanks again!

Comment: thanks @Steve
i don't know if it's a good sign or not, but it now responds with "no results". Yet, I have one item with the ID mentioned in the .php (http://postimg.org/image/3pvw6zqpd/) and I was expecting the php to solve everything. Is it possibly incomplete or something?

Comment: Well when i visit the url in my browser i am seeing a bunch errors, the main one being `(HY000/1130): Host '31.170.160.99' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server in...` so i guess your mysqli connection is still broken

Comment: Jeez! Sorry and thanks for the Help @Steve. Hostinger does not let my domain work, 000webhost does not let me upload .csv
I'll give it some time for them to reply. Hopefully the Java class should work!

Comment: Well i dont want to be the bearer of bad news, but the Java wont work either - the php code is responding with HTML but the java expects JSON :-(

Comment: damn, does it mean I have to rewrite the .php from scratch??

Comment: print(json_encode($rows));

got it. I will investigate on Hostinger, now, thanks for the help @Steve !

Comment: Pretty close - that will only work if you have exactly one result from the db query. When you get the hosting sorted, write a new question and ping me, and i'll see if i can help further. Good luck

Comment: Thanks a lot @Steve. Is there any way I can, somehow, assign you points on StackOverFlow?

Comment: Hi again @Steve, I finally found a deecnt free webhosting and my subdomain is http://marcodr.byethost7.com/

among all my thousands attempts, the .php I am working on (and updated in the thread) is "Byethost".

As you can see, my Table is really basic
http://postimg.org/image/7gx8rrsa5/

I tried several questions here in SOF, but nothing really helped !

Comment: TP2 is great,just syntax error!

Comment: Well the error is the same as before, in php you cannot have a slash in a variable name, so $P/W is causing the error. What are you using to write this code, any decent IDE should pick up these errors for you.

Comment: Sorry, sorry, my bad, I hadn't amended the text completely!

answer: http://postimg.org/image/86crp00mb/
php http://postimg.org/image/qnrvi9b5l/
my super simple DB http://postimg.org/image/5tfi5vps5/
MySQL syntax/text http://postimg.org/image/l4nxqiur9/

Comment: `"...FROM \`TABLE 1\`"` you need to put back ticks around the table name, or rename it to something without a space

Comment: $sql = 'SELECT ID, Price, Weight, PW FROM "TABLE1"';

and still

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"TABLE1"' at line 1

Comment: @Steve, I did it, I did it! Guess where was the mistake! I did not realise I needed ` instead of ' ! you can now try to see the doc TP2 where I also applied a WHERE condition!

Comment: Great, glad you got it working

Comment: I only have a last question: I recently shifted to a way simpler .php 
http://postimg.org/image/n957youzt/
which works out greatly (http://marcodr.byethost7.com/fahmi.php)

but I can't get the values out in my MainActivity class code, in the part where I parse JSON data
http://postimg.org/image/i62zm2zbz/